# implementation of linear regression, values of weights increases to Inf

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am implementing a program that performs linear regression on the following dataset:

http://www.rossmanchance.com/iscam2/data/housing.txt

My program is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def abline(X,theta,Y):
    yValues=calcH(X,theta)
    plt.xlim(0, 5000)
    plt.ylim(0, 2000000)
    plt.xlabel("sqft")
    plt.ylabel("price")
    plt.gca().set_aspect(0.001, adjustable='box')
    plt.plot(X,Y,'.',X, yValues, '-')
    plt.show() 

def openFile(fileR):
    f=pd.read_csv(fileR,sep="\t")
    header=f.columns.values
    prediction=f["price"]
    X=f["sqft"] 
    gradientDescent(0.0005,100,prediction,X)

def calcH(X,theta):
    h=np.dot(X,theta)
    return h

def calcC(X,Y,theta):
    d=((calcH(X,theta)-Y)**2).mean()/2
    return d


def gradientDescent(learningRate,itera, Y, X):
    t0=[]
    t1=[]
    cost=[]
    theta=np.zeros(2) 
    X=np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X)),X)) 
    for i in range(itera):
        h_theta=calcH(X,theta)
        theta0=theta[0]-learningRate*(Y-h_theta).mean()
        theta1=theta[1]-learningRate*((Y-h_theta)*X[:,1]).mean()
        theta=np.array([theta0,theta1])
        j=calcC(X,Y,theta)
        t0.append(theta0)
        t1.append(theta1)
        cost.append(j)
        if (i%10==0):
             print ("iteration ",i,"cost ",j,"theta ",theta)
             abline(X,theta,Y)
```

The problem that I have is that when I got my results the values of theta ends up to Inf. I have tested with only 3 iterations and some values are as follows:

```
iteration  0 cost  9.948977633931098e+21 theta  [-2.47365759e+04 -6.10382173e+07]
iteration  1 cost  7.094545903263138e+32 theta  [-6.46495395e+09 -1.62995849e+13]
iteration  2 cost  5.059070733255204e+43 theta  [-1.72638812e+15 -4.35260862e+18]
```

I would like to predict the price based on the variable sqft. I am basically following the formulas given by Andrew Ng in its Coursera ML course:

[image]

[image]

[image]

By deriving the term I got the update rule:

[image]

Update: I have added a function to plot my data and, strange, I got the following plots which are not correct:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Because it seems that my predictions are going up.

but when I plot the relationship is clearly lineal:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: everything seems correct. I suspect you're using too big learning rate. As a side note, the update step can be written as `theta -= learning_rate*np.dot(X.T, calcH(X, theta) - Y) / n`

Comment: thanks @Marat, I have added some plots that maybe could help

Comment: Ok, there is one thing: `(Y-h_theta)` should be the reverse: `(h_theta - Y)`. then, it worked for me with lr=0.00000005

Comment: BTW, I assume this is an SGD exercise because you can solve linear regression analytically (i.e. using formulas, without SGD)

Comment: thanks @Marat, well it was only that I was curious on how to apply SGD like Andrew Ng course, but not using any library. The thing is that I am a little bit worried that the cost function is too high

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your results. Besides some stylistic issues and the reversing of `(Y-h_theta)` and `(h_theta - Y)` (as pointed out in one of the comments), the actual code is correct. It's just that the numbers are massive and it easily causes the results to overdo the gradient every iteration and oscillate between extremes, each time trying to "counteract" the last step with an even bigger step to the other direction. A very low learning rate could work. In real world applications, you could also [normalize your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) to address some of these issues.