# Gradient descent function with linear descent and multivariate data resulting in null

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I understand that variables of this question have been asked on Stack Overflow, but I have been struggling to create a working gradient descent function for multivariate data. It has continually finished in null, no matter how I try to optimise it. I have created the algorithm in python.

Here is the update_weights function:

```
def update_weights(weights,targets,features):
  learn = 0.0001

  size = features[:,0]
  beds = features[:,1]
  baths = features[:,2]
  offers = features[:,3]
  loc = features[:,4]
  prediction = predict(features,weights)

  d_w1 = -size*(targets-prediction)
  d_w2 = -beds*(targets-prediction)
  d_w3 = -baths*(targets-prediction)
  d_w4 = -offers*(targets-prediction)
  d_w5 = -loc*(targets-prediction)

  weights[0][0] -= (learn*np.mean(d_w1))
  weights[1][0] -= (learn*np.mean(d_w2))
  weights[2][0] -= (learn*np.mean(d_w3))
  weights[3][0] -= (learn*np.mean(d_w4))
  weights[4][0] -= (learn*np.mean(d_w5))

  return weights
```

then I update it with a training function:

```
def train(weights,targets,features):
  cost_history = []

  for i in range(100):
      weights = update_weights(weights,targets,features)

      prediction = predict(features,weights)
      cost = error(targets,prediction)
      cost_history.append(cost)

      if i % 50 == 0:
          print('Prediction: {}'.format(prediction[0][0]))
          print('Target: {}'.format(target[0][0]))
          print('Cost: {}'.format(cost))
          print('Weights: {}'.format(weights))

  return weights
```

as I said previously, this ends in null, not getting close to the minimal value.

I would love some help to figure out how to finish this off, also I am considerably new to this so if I have completely messed everything up please be light on me:)

Thanks

Comment: You're right, this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740947/). Use smaller learning rate or normalization. Also, vectorizing update weights would make it faster and more readable

Comment: Hi @Marat, I have tried reducing the learning rate and am actively using a normalization algorithm, I will try vectorizing my weights but need to look about how (I'm quite new) apart from these issues is there a major problem with any of these formula's?

Comment: Update, I did some stuff to my normalization algorithm to make it work more accurately and I made my learning rate to 0.00000001 and behaved much more accurately, thanks for the help :)